# Изменить порядок файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

```
In[]
all_files 
out[]
[1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-1.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-1.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-1.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-1.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-2.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-2.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-2.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-2.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-2.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-2.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-3.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-3.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-3.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-3.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-3.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-3.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-4.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-4.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-4.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-4.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-4.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-4.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-5.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-5.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-5.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-5.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-5.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-5.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-6.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-6.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-6.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-6.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-6.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-6.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-7.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-7.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-7.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-7.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_-7.000_8.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_0.000_0.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_0.000_10.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_0.000_2.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_0.000_4.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_0.000_6.000.s2p',
1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p']
```

Как отсортировать список имен файлов чтобы оно начиналось с файла 0.000_0.000 до -7.000_10.000
Желаймый результат:

```
['1multibias_spar_0.000_0.000.s2p',
 '1multibias_spar_0.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_8.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_10.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_6.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_8.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_8.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_10.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_0.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_2.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_4.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_0.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_2.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_4.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_6.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_8.000.s2p', 
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p']
```

Comment: Приведите в порядок вопрос. У вас в вписке стоки или что? где открывающие кавычки? и где ваш код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызываем сортировку с ключом сортировки. Ключом будут 2 числа, полученных из названии файла:

```
def get_key(file_name: str) -> (int, int):
    m = re.search(r'_-?([.\d]+)_-?([.\d]+)\.s2p', file_name)
    num1 = m.group(1).replace('.', '')
    num2 = m.group(2).replace('.', '')
    return int(num1), int(num2)
```

Пример:

```
import re


def get_key(file_name: str) -> (int, int):
    m = re.search(r'_-?([.\d]+)_-?([.\d]+)\.s2p', file_name)
    num1 = m.group(1).replace('.', '')
    num2 = m.group(2).replace('.', '')
    return int(num1), int(num2)


items = ['1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p']

needs = ['1multibias_spar_0.000_0.000.s2p',
 '1multibias_spar_0.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_0.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-1.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-2.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-3.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-4.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-5.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-6.000_10.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_0.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_2.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_4.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_6.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_8.000.s2p',
'1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p']


items.sort(key=get_key)
print(items)
print(needs)
print(items == needs)
```

Результат:

```
['1multibias_spar_0.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p']
['1multibias_spar_0.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_0.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-1.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-2.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-3.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-4.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-5.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-6.000_10.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_0.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_2.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_4.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_6.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_8.000.s2p', '1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p']
True
```

Comment: Почему после 0.000_8.000 идет уже -1.000_0.000. А 0.000_10.000 переноситься в конец списка. Как исправить?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin потому что по лямбде из `'1multibias_spar_0.000_8.000.s2p'` получится число `1000080002`, а из `'1multibias_spar_-1.000_0.000.s2p'` получится `1100000002`. В конце списка ведь `'1multibias_spar_-7.000_10.000.s2p'`, а не `0.000_10.000`

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, по-моему, у меня отсортировалось правильно, как по условию в вопросе: `"0.000_0.000 до -7.000_10.000"` :)

Comment: А можно сделать так что бы 0.000_0.000 ->0.000_10.000 ; -1.000_0.000->-1.000_10.000 ; -2.000_0.000-> -2.000_10.000; И так далее.

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, добавьте в вопрос ожидаемый результат, вы предоставили пример входящего списка, покажите как должен выглядеть результат

Comment: Добавил желаемый результат в описание вопроса

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, обновил ответ :) Т.к. условие сортировки стало сложнее, поменял код получения ключа, теперь оно вытаскивает 2 числа из названия. Кст, сначала я вытаскивал и минус, но это не проходило проверку с вашим результатом, поэтому убрал из захвата минусы и сортировка показала такой же результат как вы привели

Comment: Хорошая работа)

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Такой ключ вроде дает тот же результат:

```
from re import search

files = sorted(items, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, search(r'_-?(\d+).+_(\d+)', x).groups())))
```